# Feature Importance - Isolation regression forest

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running an isolation regression forest on a set of data that I get automated on a daily basis. The application is set that any feature can be used as the inputs of the model as it is dynamic pertaining to the use case.

So, if I want to know which feature have contributed more to the anomalous behavior, is it possible? I cannot train the data based off the output as the algorithm can be used for any number of features.

Any help in this regard will be great.

Comment: please give use sample data, script(s) that you are working on.

Comment: Hi Vidya, There is no existing solution for feature importance in Isolation forest available. One suggestion could be using a surrogate model on the prediction of isolation forest and then use the feature importance of surrogate model